# Swift get Facebook user email not working

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook

let request = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/permissions", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email,picture.type(large),birthday"])

Im able to retrieve all of the other infos except for email. Im not sure if facebook book no longer allow retrieval of email.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you should be still able to get it according to this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/) by Facebook. 
Make sure you have `"email"` in the parameters will you perform login and get the accessToken.

```
let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
let handler = ...
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, fromViewController: self, handler: handler)
```

Then you can use that accessToken to perform graph request for email.
Also make sure your email is verified for your facebook account.